# Check if an input is anywhere in a list

Tags: python, list, file, input

So I have this code below:

It works by accepting a user input that is in an external list file, but I would like it to accept an input from the user, and then check if that input is anywhere in the external file. Right now, it only accepts the first line as the first user, then the other lines. I want it to accept the input, even if it isn't the first line of the code.

```
with open("users.txt") as f:
    lines = set("users.txt")
    x = input("First Player, please enter a valid username and password (In the form: Username , Password): ")
    for lines in f:
        if (x) in ("users.txt"):
             lines2 = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in open("users.txt")]
             y = input("Second Player, please enter a valid username and password (In the form: Username , Password): ")
             for lines in f:
                if (y) in ("users.txt"):
```

I've tried simple code, up to more complex code such as:

```
if (y in lines for y in lines)
```

Comment: Update: It only works if I enter the inputs from the file in order.

Comment: `x in "users.txt"` checks if `x` is in the *string* `"users.txt"`, not the file *named* "users.txt".

Answer (score 0):

You are working with the name of the file rather than the contents of the file.

```
with open("users.txt") as f:
    allowed_names = set(line.strip() for line in f)

x = input("First player name, password")
p1_name, p1_password = x.split(",")

y = input("Second player name, password")
p2_name, p2_password = y.split(",")

if p1_name in allowed_names:
    ...

if p2_name in allowed_names:
    ...
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much. I now realise it was kind of a stupid question to ask.